# How to position two divs side by side in a browser window, centered

Tags: html, css

Could somebody please show me how to position two divs horizontally side by side, centered within the browser window?

They need to be exactly the same width and height but with a gap in between them of 'not a lot'. As well as making them responsive.

I have looked on stack for the answer but none of the answers cover what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have looked on stack???? What is this

Comment: stack overflow, I have googled it too :(

Comment: Haha It happens sometimes. Just kidding

Comment: Learn how to use CSS param like `float`, `margin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approch for that is to use [Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) with [the calc() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)  together.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0} /*reset all browser style*/

:root{background: black; min-height: 100vh; width: 100vw} /*set the root element to viewport*/

body{ text-align: center} /*ask the browser to set the box in the middle of the screen*/

article{
  background: white;
  width: calc(50vw - 40px);  /*reserve 20x2px for the margin*/
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);  /*reserve 10x2px for the margin*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 10px   
}
```

```html
<article></article>
<article></article>
```

But you can use percentage too

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}

:root{background: black; min-height: 100vh}

section{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center
}

article{
  background: white;
  width: 48%;
  height: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5% auto
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<style>
        #main { 
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #sidebar    {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: red;
        float: left;
    }

    #page-wrap  {
        width: 400px;
        background: yellow;
        height: 400px;
        float: right;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="sidebar"></div>
      <div id="page-wrap"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/8uwcs679/

I've created two divs of 40% width. left div have margin right of 5%.
Hence total width remaining = 100% - (40%+40%+5%) = 15%;

Then I've set margin left of left div to 15%/2 = 7.5% which will center the divs and it will  be responsive too.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="side left"></div>
<div class="side right"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.side{
    float: left;
    width:40%;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.left {
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-div">
     <div class="child-one"></div>
     <div class="child-two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent-div{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.child-one, child-two{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
.child-one{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

height of the div's will be determined by content inside them.

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly the same **height** I suggest to use `flexbox`.

```css
body { /* or use extra wrapper element */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
body > div {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 .25em; /* for gap */
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div>first. equal height by default. equal height by default. equal height by default. equal height by default. equal height by default. equal height by default. equal height by default. equal height by default. </div>
<div>second</div>
```